# Everything works but not adding data to mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm trying to add some data to my database. Code works good without error. But when i'm checking my database i see that there is nothing new. Where is error?

```
import MySQLdb as mdb

con = #connection settings
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO myData(id,city,district,testval,
        test_date,property_type,price,testvar,title,
        description,number_of_tester,number_of_test,
        test_age,test_number,number_of_tests,heating,test_type,
        applicable,usage_type,test_profile,test,
        house_type,latitude,longitude,test_name,test_phones,test_profile,
        test_desc,test_title)
        VALUES (123456,'Baku','Ahmedli rn','Ahmadli',
            '2010-11-10 12:00:00','',1,0,'','','',0,'','','','','','','','','','',0,0,'','','','','')""")
con.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved, MySQL in Python needs con.commit() at the end to add all this to datebase.

Comment: Its not MySQL, its the db api that needs it. See the [specs](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#commit) for more information.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid original code was in ruby, that is why i didn't used commit()